# Can i change any key to make my pc "power on"?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, remapping

Hello I would like to ask how do i remap any key to power on/off my pc? I used .exe program called SharpKeys(there is option the remap delete key to "Power" but i dont know if it only do on/off or both), I want to remap my Delete key to power on and off my laptop since my real power button got broken off so im putting my laptop to sleep every since so i can wake up my laptop just with a keyboard. Once i powered my laptop off making me disassemble the whole laptop so i can just unplug the battery plug the charger in so it will start up......... laptop: Lenovo ideapad 100-15idb

Comment: Your power button isn’t connected to the keyboard PCB.  You should take your device to a technician.  Those push buttons are easily replaced by somebody with experience

Comment: Power on and off is a function of the hardware and power switch. At best you can get a key set to turn the power off as the shutdown function of the OS. But after that there is nothing to turn the laptop on because no OS is running.

Comment: Thank you for your information, i tried to look up for power button replacement but no luck. Is there option on my laptop that it will power on by keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

No keyboard key can be the solution, since it is only used *after power-on*.

The [Lenovo Ideapad 100-15IBD manual](https://cdn.cnetcontent.com/a3/5b/a35ba9d9-004d-4f61-a8ff-4893f51a5a81.pdf)
has this on page 5:

---

[image]

---

The Novo button, which looks like a pin-hole, could be the solution.
Insert an open paper clip in the hole and push to start the computer.

If it does not work, in the BIOS menu, under Power management, you might find
an option to switch on by just re-attaching the AC adapter.